# When I create a variable to a function using "await", this function runs immediately or just when I call this variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I do this:

```
conn = await pool.getConnection()
```

getConnection() runs?

Or runs just when I call the conn variable? Like this:

```
conn.execute(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`);
```

Comment: With `getConnection()`, you *are* already calling the `getConnection` method

Comment: So it does run?

My question is if this line is just a reference that does nothing, or if it already performs something

Comment: When you put `()` after a function, you invoke the function, so if the function does something, invoking it will do something. Nothing to do with `await`

Comment: Wow, I get it!. Thanks! :D

Comment: There is no such thing as a "reference (to an expression)" in javascript.

Comment: This question is poorly written because `something()` has nothing to do with `await pool.getConnection()`  And ```sql = conn.execute(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`);``` has nothing to do with anything written before that .  So it's hard to how the lines of your example are related and it's hard to know what your question is.  Sounds like you have questions about `await`.  Sounds like you need to know about the nuances of _async_ functions.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited to make more clearly. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
conn = await pool.getConnection()
```

`pool.connection()` runs immediately.  The `()` tell Javascript to execute the method now.  In this case, `pool.getConnection()` starts the process of getting a database connection and then immediately returns a promise (assuming you're using a version of your DB library that supports promises).

The `await` operates on that promise and suspends furather execution of this `asycn` function until that promise resolves and the containing `async` function itself returns a promise.  When the database connection promise resolves, the variable `conn` is assigned the resolved value of that promise (which should be a live database connection object) and then the execution of the function continues.

`pool.getConnection` would be a function reference.  `pool.getConnection()` executes that function and it's value will be the return value from executing the `.getConnection()` method.

> When I create a reference to a function using “await”

This statement of yours is a bit confused.  Using `await` does not "create a reference to a function".  If you do `await somePromise`, that just suspends further execution of the function body until that promise resolves or rejects.  In your case `pool.getConnection()` is executed and its return value is what `await` gets.

Comment: Although my question was poorly written you answered exactly what I needed.
Thanks!